# Display numbers on a tray icon with SWT

Tags: java, swt, system-tray, trayicon, tray

I would like to show some numbers on my tray icon indicating a number of events that happened to the user like what is done in this facebook notifications icons:

[image]

Do you think that it is possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `TaskBar` and `TaskItem` classes although it may not work on all platforms.

```
TaskBar taskBar = Display.getDefault().getSystemTaskBar();
// TODO may return null if not supported on the platform

// Get application item

TaskItem taskItem = taskBar.getItem(null);
if (taskItem != null)
  taskItem.setOverlayText("your text");
```

Also try:

```
TaskItem taskItem = taskBar.getItem(shell);
```

where `shell` is your main application shell. The `TaskItem` JavaDoc suggests trying both methods of getting the `TaskItem`:

> For better cross platform support, the application code should first
>   try to set this feature on the TaskItem for the main shell then on the
>   TaskItem for the application.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Is there any solution with `TrayItem` ?

Comment: `TrayItem` only has `setImage` (and `setTooltipText`). You could construct an image with the overlay text.

Comment: Thnx. Any hint for the construction of the image with the overlay text ?

Comment: You could also try `taskBar.getItem(shell)` where `shell` is your main application shell.

Comment: Didn't work with the `shell`, how can I stack images to construct the icon with the numbers on the top ?

Comment: Look at something like `DecorationOverlayIcon`

Comment: It worked with the `DecorationOverlayIcon` but I can't have the number on the top right like the one on the example on top.

Is there a way to overlay with text instead of images ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92262/discussion-between-marouane-and-greg-449).

Comment: I have nothing else to add to this.